# Generating a non BOOLEAN result to a CSV using R

Tags: sql, r, csv

I have taken over a report from a college who has left the organisation. The report is written in R, it  accesses an Oracle database, and runs SQL scripts into R.

The R code then pushes the data out to a csv. The difficulty I have is that it is pushing `TRUE`, `FALSE` or a blank cell to the csv. I want to update the code to print `Updated`, `Not Updated`, or a blank cell. I am struggling to find the correct place to make these updates.

Below is the code that generates the CSV, as well as a snippet that the code refers to, that may be generating the `TRUE` and `FALSE` that I referred to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# prepare a data frame based on Today_Active_address_wf for printing. 
ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf <- Today_Active_address_wf

# add an empty row to dataframe
ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf[nrow(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf)+1, ] <- NA

# write today Active address wf data frame to .csv file
filename <- paste("Daily Address Change Workflow Report___", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d__%Hh%M"), ".csv", sep ="")
filelocation <- "\\\\DCV-PANAPP-P001\\File Share\\BIS\\Data Administration\\Daily Workflow Reports\\"
filewrite <- paste(filelocation, filename, sep = "")
write.csv(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf, file = filewrite, row.names = FALSE, na="")

# add additional info (totals for each column)
addInfo1 <- c("Total_duplicated_WF"
              ,"Total_inconsistent_wf_addr"
              ,"Total_QAS_validated_addr"
              ,"Total_invalid_Wf_addr_date"
              ,"Postal_unmatched_with_valid_WF"
              ,"Total_No_Policy"
              ,"Total_home_risk"
              ,"Total_motor_risk"
              ,"Total_risk_addr_change"
  )
addInfo2 <- c(sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$dupCloseFlag, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$inconsistentDataFlag, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$WF_ADDRESS_VALIDATED, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$valid_addr_date == FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$MatchedPO_WF_addr == FALSE & ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$valid_addr_date == TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$hasNOpolicy, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$hasHomeRisk, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$hasMotorRisk, na.rm = TRUE)
              ,sum(ForPrintONLYToday_Active_address_wf$riskAddrChange_Flag, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
addInfoTable <- as.table(setNames(addInfo2, addInfo1))

write.table(addInfoTable, file = filewrite, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, na="",append = TRUE, sep = ":,")

### Additional Function ###

# function that converts "Y" to TRUE and "N" to FALSE
yn_to_logical <- function(x) {
 y <- rep.int(NA, length(x))
y[x == "Y"] <- TRUE
y[x == "N"] <- FALSE
y
} '
```

Thanks all, I know this is a pile of code, but R is not my strong point.

Comment: Can you see if `y[x == "Y"] <- TRUE` can be changed to `y[x == "Y"] <- "Updated"` and see if you get the desired results? Vice versa for the `FALSE`?

Comment: Perfect, your solution worked. I had been put off by the IDE (R Studio) which had thrown warnings on this approach. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to replace one set of values with another set of values. Here is one way:

```
# Create a simple data set that contains a column with "Y","N" and NAs (missing values) 
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c("Y","N",NA), 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 val = rnorm(10) )
df
#       x         val
# 1     N  0.56554865
# 2  <NA> -1.81437749
# 3     Y -1.21385694
# 4     Y -1.30173545
# 5     N -0.18994710
# 6     N -0.67519801
# 7  <NA>  0.02093869
# 8     N  0.69082204
# 9     Y  0.01715652
# 10    Y  1.34007199

# use function recode() from car package
library(car)
df$x <- recode(df$x, " 'Y' = 'Updated'; 'N' = 'Not Updated'")
df
#      x         val
# 1  Not Updated  0.56554865
# 2         <NA> -1.81437749
# 3      Updated -1.21385694
# 4      Updated -1.30173545
# 5  Not Updated -0.18994710
# 6  Not Updated -0.67519801
# 7         <NA>  0.02093869
# 8  Not Updated  0.69082204
# 9      Updated  0.01715652
# 10     Updated  1.34007199
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I am now updating the script and am using (car). Thanks very much for your help.